# How to call Salesforce metadata rest api from curl php

Tags: php, salesforce, php-curl, salesforce-lightning, sfdc-metadata-api

I am trying to deploy metadata records from PHP to salesforce org using salesforce metadata REST API.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_rest_deploy.htm

As per documentation, we are supposed to send the data in subparts

```
POST /services/data/v48.0/metadata/deployRequest
Authorization: Bearer 00D....
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------BOUNDARY
----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
Content-Type: application/json
{ 
    "deployOptions" :
        {
        "allowMissingFiles" : false,
        "autoUpdatePackage" : false,
        "checkOnly" : false,
        "ignoreWarnings" : false,
        "performRetrieve" : false,
        "purgeOnDelete" : false,
        "rollbackOnError" : false,
        "runTests" : null,
        "singlePackage" : true,
        "testLevel" : "RunAllTestsInOrg"
        }
    }
----------------------------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="deploy.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip

//Contents of deploy.zip
----------------------------BOUNDARY--
```

Below is my PHP code

```
public function deployCustomMetadata($serviceUrl, $sessionid){
        
        $posturl = $serviceUrl.'services/data/v48.0/metadata/deployRequest';
        $filedata = file_get_contents(PACKAGE_PATH);

        list($request_headers, $form) = $this->create_upload_form_for_datachunk($filedata, $sessionid);
        $fp = fopen('./packages//errorlog.txt', 'w');
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $posturl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);         
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, implode("\r\n", $form));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
        $data = curl_exec($ch); 
        print_r($data);
    }

    function create_upload_form_for_datachunk($data, $sessionid) {
        $deployOptions = json_encode(array("deployOptions" => 
                array(
                        "allowMissingFiles" => false,
                        "autoUpdatePackage" => false,
                        "checkOnly" => false,
                        "ignoreWarnings" => false,
                        "performRetrieve" => false,
                        "purgeOnDelete" => false,
                        "rollbackOnError" => false,
                        "runTests" => null,
                        "singlePackage" => true,
                        "testLevel" => "RunAllTestsInOrg"
                    )
        ));
       
        $headers = array();
        $form[] = implode("\r\n", array(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filedata\"; filename=\"blob\"",
            "Content-Type: application/octet-stream",
            "",
            $data,
            "blob"
        ));
     
        // generate safe boundary
        do {
            $boundary = "---------------------" . md5(mt_rand() . microtime());
        } while (preg_grep("/{$boundary}/", $form));
     
        // add boundary for each parameters
        array_walk($form, function (&$part) use ($boundary) {
            $part = "--{$boundary}\r\n{$part}";
        });
     
        // add final boundary
        $form[] = "--{$boundary}--";
        $form[] = "";
     
        // set options
        $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer  ".$sessionid;
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary={$boundary}";
       
        $headers[] = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"json\" ";
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json ".$deployOptions.$boundary;
        $headers[] = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"  ; filename=\"deploy.zip\"  ";
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/zip".$boundary;
        
        return array($headers, $form);
    }
```

It always throws me error **An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1629748103-90297 (-1851675661)**

Can anyone help me in sending request body in subparts including the the zip file.

Comment: So what does what you are sending actually look like? Does `implode("\r\n", $form)` match the format you are supposed to send?

Comment: @CBroe when I check in debug log. It looks like the same format. but still the same error. Is there any alternative way to send the request in subparts?

Comment: That error is a gack, an internal unexpected error. Validate your zip file by deploying it through Workbench to determine whether the metadata itself, or the deployment call, is at fault. Either may be the case.

Comment: @DavidReed I have tested the zip file via the workbench and it successfully got deployed. I guess there is something wrong in the request format.

Comment: Try [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256731/deploying-metadata-with-rest-resources) by @Zach Hutchins. It might help.